# JHipster - add a relationship to jhi_user_authority

Tags: javascript, spring-data, jhipster

I'm acutually trying to make a one-to-many relationship between the auto generated table "jhi_user_authority" and my own table called socialMediaFilter.

My situation is the following:

On the one side I have users, these are saved in the table "jhi_user" these users have roles and the roles for themselves are saved in a table called "jhi_authority". Between users and roles is a many-to-many relation, that means that many users can have many roles. These relationships are saved in a join-table called "jhi_user_authority". All these 3 tables are auto-generated by Jhipster when I created the project.

In my project I need to add some filters for filtering data from social media networks, twitter, fb and so on. A filter belongs to a role and a role can have many filters. So between these two tables is a one-to-many relationship and I'm struggling implementing this in my project.

I cannot access these auto-generated tables with the jhipster:entity generator. When I'm using for example yo jhipster:entity authority jhipster tries to generate a new entity. And as far as I know - these auto-generated tables are not meant to be accessed by the entity-generator. So when I want to edit them I need to edit them manually, so I can not follow the instructions in the tutorial.

Is there maybe someone who can pushes me to right direction? :D

thanks, 
Alex

EDIT:
okay...after thinking for a while i figured out that i need to do it different

the relationships i need to implement should be like this [uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExJwY.png)

but i still have problems realizing it

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, you have to do an n-m relation with the "Authority" class, in which you must specify that the relationship table is "jhi_user_authority"